# Drag & drop files through VSphere

Tags: vmware-esx

Is it possible to drag & drop a file from my desktop to a ESX`s guest via VSphere Client ( i mean drag & drop it to the guest`s console) like I do between any file on my desktop and a VM Workstation`s guest ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible and I believe it is that way by design. Only the client products like workstation can do this.  Imagine you are being hosted on an ESX infrastructure, do you really want Dr. Blackhat on a VM on the same farm to be able to get anywhere near the ESX infrastructure?

Comment: Agreed, nopey nope nopes - and for good reason too :)

Comment: oh and I've just spotted, we're just around the corner from each other, I'm in Christchurch - small world!

Answer (score 1):

If only, If Only. I've only found that works via VM Fusion OR Vmware Workstation sorry to say.